# JAX WS error http 302 (found) DIAN Colombia

Tags: java, webservice, soap

Estoy utilizando la herramienta JAX-WS RI para acceder al servicio web de pruebas de la DIAN que es el siguiente

https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl

El xml que me genera el codigo es el siguiente, aunque tuve que agregar la cabecera por separado ya que la herramienta no proporciona dicha generacion:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>xxx</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">MzExODQ2MzU3MAo</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">2018-10-31T16:34:33.762Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion xmlns="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
        <rep:NIT>1030683938</rep:NIT>
        <rep:InvoiceNumber>990000003</+rep:InvoiceNumber>
        <rep:IssueDate>2018-11-06T10:55:20.648-05:00</rep:IssueDate>
        <rep:Document>UEsDBBQACAgIAPpNTU0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAZmFjdHVyYS54bWzlWuly4kqW/t2O8Dso6IiOmWBA+0aX3SEhsdiIHQz8qUiklBBoAS0sfpt+gH6B+Tn3xSa1sNm4usq3q2/UjMNFoJNn/06e1Mnyl7/tXQfbwiC0fe+hQJaJAgY93Tdsz3oojIa1klDAwgh4BnB8Dz4UPL/wt8cvJqw0va1v6xBD8l5Y0YH+UIgDr+KD0A4rHnBhWAnXULdNWwcRUl6J504l1BfQBZV9aFSqvuv6nmRZAbRABNHjGhnworBEFY5K559TKiN2/aZCx2UZiuQzrXHyC3WIPnVoAj2qoLihY4fRGyOpTIUiCPJCEccxJPmDilKZt4qaUlvSmpqqQcMGw8Ma/qDSd/KJAfpoAO6jT+VQ3UfQS4riVh43xo8q7cXAQYvQUEAEIuTkhbYwCh8KiyhaV3B8t9uVURhe2fK3Zd3Hdd+LAhD5IZ6kIA4AdKAeBb6H7OBbEh9EQZzQYXjUFh99e59AA9l+4+bI21x6lqQvHKRua74ROyiXR7370L7yckeX/cDCEzDxidbKhEq2l2wWHSKp0M4T0PIzY58NEiuXcZRDXEFIfx3JrTJ6wP6FESb60S9CjEKuJODjN4QuZUpUmTh58btq4JZtuVW6xZqZLDx+QSVdQUynCg3fkzLKRQ176Fv0+AWVWkVBmb+UTWh5M0v4At+5oklxtPAD+zUN6VEk0h8W/SN5kSO+4B+ypkquSF0Y2L7x+AX1tcogAkGEooOPFEFyJYIvkeQX/HolZVQ948gmXLId6ZkHN+1cLkAjdzKPuBtA094/dvsjNdOQE9LFWuC7j6KQxZrHmNLS1aGP1tjLNUS5duPSGv5PEjzw40DPg20aCKZTAVVRw8OSjidZ6Ew6NJWHAle4ILRRzaFDyrMjaGDtVCTEVLSbfNfWsaSP2WECMmb6AabGgb+GmXhay3DUb35PFzu1XUtHvTFGARzeu5mUZ+Gx2smweb9+nYZjyIg08M1oBwLYDfytbcDgiE721FSwdAPBcwZIkS1cEbMsVDv/hSUNAvsPxQ6gridho+w13XUMQ9RasAMmGTHwQIgylawCB4b/WUgKmuZpkmSPVXA0nDlydO/nO0IYFKQEgS7BuWCUGIrmSwJvosQKAM55EoocCTMfzz5lWb2dwiN1APU4sKNDWkw/OYa5AQBL6qLI0pAQDF0XTFoUkOcmrxsET6JP1pxDQLMcFGme4wgASCCA+RzSpMno4pyBc1Y3BU6gINABowssRSNtFEsjbW/iv4wsr6+3vQ2/3Qbx2/3yezqogezblgeSMzc/GY3wg4ORwAkRRzxGaFt/LmBN46GQP5UEwZybOsOW6DmkSozOgJJAAx01OJGD5BwYjM4WHu/vjvaShmL6OaEKvPRsdPJ+p0HUdQxMcizUe6KFe8udYT87qvtqtYScKOkk45USCkGTbAG/MJWG9j0q30YYhKAULgB50taHJgxQVUEsbTXHeIYB8ELUktzwLeHH7EFvCx3U04xSeHQ7M43fMqLYFqrdz8R1FVOmZgycGB1JcW3Zsof1UUfqjcTDqyTpoW8KIFyvHlInLplzv045ORLeoXvC4CgHX1e8rGxsc0iQHaveNZZ1223IYt+X+sOeMo02g9mKBYMwwPfrpy0F5Flt/sz3G0+SLlKs2uy6DX085WrBrnp/J7PQrHXU7dRyN7wVLNWFJfpsS1ZEedUarV8a042xkl9JZlrbvVTrT23ieTdjViTliDFotqSoWZ+tQ16a0yP3/m4xAfs5x/UXTGMvywvRJRvmdtDSKGL1wnDjRSNcronWfvhcnPU7YLsdT0K7fiCVuVjTCY6b0M+dNb3e7bvRbHV/J1FhW50Pa71qPSJhs9tYSLG6lMTaQCRe60+csLWb+q7Wq80jxjTr/krx5wxYFdmV+NoJl5wy3IRMIPe1pcvf31Xp9v45rjXX3n5I9Dab8UJYKa8jSYyH05dpNDYXdiuWHh4ugLjKewLGMzxcQDNhCTF5I7t4rMIgP+kSEa3ZVIxhtSo5lCXtmrJkNdWZ1akRQ6ktW6vNYmXXxR0hS72wJilyoPXCXbU3Vca9Xl3dPfX6Q7WtSWFdIkcqCkDW1GHdiaYXVHl/onU1iUhp1YVW71GiO31pb7V+c6dKqcaWunOUOTVbTClxeH/XG2n7+lCayFZ7LEvaUFXFV4OqhbO6YPXc2mFWR98n2q6x0NvaUN+1X7W9pmikNhyxLxkNPTfZhIYiTajLb0fwvf6jSL8jgu/1//7OslQ70V0dbOqD5pxWeirK+EiSmKas7KQdWn+WfIROr9qdmjgx2MdCozGGfZ1j9y/LqsM+7bg6I209EpX4UqoOJk+GEO+tvcc6+6bM7zua2ykKA/js2jxZHK2ALHR7E2HvSkCzhQ4nyp3llLOcFXD0UVtdMPPBwtEDGeWtGpOEazBhW1lpYa9va82VoAeRy85Hg7G6YudcWym29UNobNHB21sX5cV+xkTTeBsGAacuVwLTOZCvw5m1RL51CGpi7FnmiXHDPaeiFC1NZcJ7XrX9VB3J3Z4wngaKa1g9Y289ke7cXKp6OKRsH+ef+kXFrmvr53XnmTe3CIWBzHRoHqgMXD132DEYzBbP2vOMpPb2RMAnylaDzrK3CiwdJcThei8ryhkvltX6RJvsn6OotaS2W6Pf0PHX+7vd2OIlS5Mlqb5sDiVTk1O0DcXqvcjyoL1UX3ZBfU32XycqG3Vgvx33hCdDK97YK6g1SJ2q1FOl5cFgp86424PerqMCqzMSFWtpLtu+s2kd9qMnotoWhsF6v3lqsWKHHrYNtQs7O6Ntb3v0zO/RMnF/F7QGMrUt1qV6S5rEtVBasq/7harzM6pmht4WbLr1ePo6W203fY9oE6t4ZfVwViSWZsuv8kUfd18iEOoT+zW4vzMntWAPFp636NtytW6GpkdwDgCDQ8MDZmM62be7LU0OVrE3HmtFa4Tw67C94gT09ssZ2QjshV4kVXEXFdv3d1u4bk31uIuqjSSKcVWxNr61lbs1jVG9oN+BnRd35sJ6q7WLGmITyDJDN1+VpxVnGLq3XNUO8qA47W0AHKDqVQD+SrgSKp3nYnehNOLOWF3EtXaxqLS9TX3SeOq5UX+lKePBq707NcP3re1EPjZA/Lo9XrXQH3nzekcKs1kIkcbZvRx60UUPGBoxsvHiaiXlRa++pu0kb8Tpayt55DzTs/FKSQc+NNnRIikyYj6t5Kuj0c9/yydZCAmWYiiOoEzWMObGnBdYnTYMEwo8NE1mjuYRM59xE49yz8MwhudxmSTRXJB7f1o5Mw5tFz4SXIUkKzR5wZbSM7ZsEEsuNk5T5sVU+MnbqAuthZ+eyTyu60Cy6No+SscARomidRDDORJ+wDCzFCb3Fl/zmY+iv851xqS+9i9vNQRCZEtJlZSkr3pswquC+crMztIYdsYCW/uOHaE0JCZNO3BBGtRfgLv+659J+q/3d1j+047dGtAr2JXeG3w1qKd8iQ2SpAQCfdLkDUb0upIykgLDCrRYFpgbTCg3KKNkBSM+UJGvlgniQ2kKrVMfSqNVnmNIvsxzH2qgkQb6Qw1oleQFmhDK5MdmUEJIlmcpoXwzGW076tTUCnYC6QbP0F5LxqaC3VYQu+migEpBFBn6VjCDKLA96w2E1zidwUATFkoqQR2Tg+atY5DnSE7u0uTJsGEIrDFnWZZh5wbHcpxJc3PCNNDEKJpojUVtg4Mn97LtkFZ+ugcUX49d1HOrcZDMG9mUXO10M76bq8l/a0i6ntzxoPgG8Xrt2DDogiA6ZDolw7CjdAvmbKg95fvw1lKi7yiNKjT9en01dGzLP7lZ5JoSxTR5uvOh6HP/xz928LiQeJC3l+Rb9wkrncsMfUdlE9uBjaQhVlNzOFIZ/I2OJC2LQ5hM8Me78Sz3hhHAMD/+FLhGEglGjwpqzmha9bEqWNsRcHIIzwypQNWODoN4bthbOzkaU1NVmNw3Zvy31k+C6ZPsW37029/P7DkP0I+utWwvF0q//UkHqHwCgAlY+3/+G+OqKA18fi5lrPh7YXC6RvzozvPb94hXCvDLtOEfJTbN/RDssxMuM4seW3ALnVRr/rpwRUs9PQnhufo3mo6kFrSAoyJno8MlZ+7gR3vqaq0aowp2/y/ut1NL+9377aTpp+63Rmw74GdtMslew9+3w0iC/H++xTL1fWgljTH14UZLzuy9YzrbuFL44ZZ9sy3RGvJt6KM2fApSchNeTM/P0qTs0UGLXlGPB/0p9IzzJKgm9/WeDpuekQDgB48mcEJ4Yn+/nttHJRZduQDmDvzQjdO7yEnxmf13BtGFgZ5sDrHM5bv7SDliW0WjieUHhzdgnwYy4u0pfMGCv9OBv40fvwLkR9ChubJI/srIfBzAEYPkzZMiPomL8AfhwtNlgf6Vcfk4gEtcmM/iwv9BuJA8S7Nlhv+VoflmDGd0RPaT2LB/EDYsS5d59ldG5hsRXOwa+pO4vH3z/LedMQLPUWXul25n34zhiARVJj8JDfNHHTP5fcyvDM03YzgiwZRJ5pPYUP9abNIXbs33YASCwwVKydRyuv3/3kzdEDpjt9edOLS3H6adJklOEC4PgjcieQrB4Vvgne/v8vxesmfx3wr5/MfD52HvPNifbvwzFqOHxut0RKGp6yvv88pnkkgJLMWzDP2NZCZ+RtA9jsehHtjrdN5r/fYPD4ISeX0B+rnr9eOYfdae5i0znMxkgX3847j064fnB88SZYoXBRQa2hbi8aQ4y+QzXqYPfwvCBeHxfwFQSwcIXxmNb+wNAAAVLgAAUEsBAhQAFAAICAgA+k1NTV8ZjW/sDQAAFS4AAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGZhY3R1cmEueG1sUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAOQAAACUOAAAAAA==</rep:Document>
    </rep:EnvioFacturaElectronicaPeticion>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Esta peticion me devuelve ubn xml de respuesta en el SoapUI, pero en cambio en mi aplicacion me dice lo siguiente

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: El servidor ha enviado el código de estado HTTP 302: Found
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:321)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:270)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:429)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:168)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:151)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.envioFacturaElectronica(Unknown Source)
at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.envioFacturaElectronica(JavaApplication6.java:92)
at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.main(JavaApplication6.java:78)
```

No se que es lo que podría estar pasando, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Te sugiero que no coloques información real. Si la petición la estas haciendo con GET, te sugiero que ahora la hagas con POST.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Donde cambio el tipo de peticion que estoy haciendo? Ya que no veo ningún lado una, hay anotaciones como @WebMethod(operationName = "EnvioFacturaElectronica") arriba del metodo que hace la llamada al servicio, ahi debo poner la equiqueta @POST?

Answer (score 2):

Pude solucionar el problema añandiendo la siguiente linea de codigo al bindingprovider de el servicio:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl");
```

No estaba bien especificado el endpoint del servicio.